# Google BigQuery Shared Dataset and Billing Costs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, billing

Lets assume user_A is the owner of Dataset_A which belongs to project_A and he wants to share the Dataset_A with user_B (user_B default project is project_B).

After sharing Dataset_A with user_B
(Open Dataset -> Permissions -> Add Principal -> BigQuery Data Viewer role),
user_B can see project_A pinned in his BigQuery Explorer - left navbar in UI (so now he can see 2 projects project_B and newly shared project_A).

It is clear that storage costs of Dataset_A occur to project_A.
But what happens when user_B queries the shared Dataset_A (i.e of user_B queries -> SELECT * FROM project_A.Dataset_A.table) ?

The query costs/processing costs occur to project_B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user has only the BigQuery Data Viewer role in a project, he is not able to run queries in that project. So, in your example, user_B won't be able to run a query while project_A is selected.

However, if she has a more powerful role in project_B (like BigQuery Admin), she can run a query against Dataset_A from project_B. In that case, the job will be run in project_B so this is the project that will be charged.

As you mentioned, storage costs only apply to project_A. You can take a look at all the available pre-defined BQ roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

Comment: BigQuery Data Viewer role can run queries against shared dataset and only that. I have tested it.

Comment: The query jobs cannot be inserted in project_A if the user has only Data Viewer role. The charges occur to the project where the query job is inserted. That is the project that appears at the top of your screen when you are using the UI.

Comment: Each query inserts a query job to the project. You can see that if you click on "Query History". Each query has a jobID assigned to it of the format `<projectID>.<location>.<unique_job_id>`. The project ID mentioned here is the one that will be billed for the query.

Comment: I found it. Great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If User_B can just *access* the data from Project_A, Bigquery usage will be billed to Project_B.

User_B can only make charges in Project_A *if* BigQuery retrieves data from a storage bucket inside Project_A.

To avoid this scenario, you could set [requester pays](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays) in that Bucket.